# Trying to get value from hash table in C returns some random value instead of value

Tags: c, hashmap, hashtable, gnu

I am using a hash table library in C, but it seems that whenever I retrieve the value of some key in a different function than where I entered the key-value pair, I get some random value instead of the actual value.

If I get a value from the hash table using a key within the same function that I placed it, everything works fine. But, when I place the key-value pair into the hashtable in one function and then try to retrieve it in another function, it spits out a random new value each time instead of the expected value. I have tried 3 different libraries (GNU Hash table, UTHash, and Ben Hoyt's Implementation, all of which I link below) and none of them work across functions. I assume this is not a problem with the libraries, then, and something wrong with how I am retrieving the values. I have included a screenshot below of what the code and output looks like, and the current code I am using for the hash table.

[image: Screenshot]

ht.c:

```
#include "ht.h"

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Hash table entry (slot may be filled or empty).
typedef struct {
    const char* key;  // key is NULL if this slot is empty
    void* value;
} ht_entry;

#define INITIAL_CAPACITY 16  // must not be zero

// Hash table structure: create with ht_create, free with ht_destroy.
typedef struct ht {
    ht_entry* entries;  // hash slots
    size_t capacity;    // size of _entries array
    size_t length;      // number of items in hash table
};

ht* ht_create(void) {
    // Allocate space for hash table struct.
    ht* table = malloc(sizeof(ht));
    if (table == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    table->length = 0;
    table->capacity = INITIAL_CAPACITY;

    // Allocate (zero'd) space for entry buckets.
    table->entries = calloc(table->capacity, sizeof(ht_entry));
    if (table->entries == NULL) {
        free(table); // error, free table before we return!
        return NULL;
    }
    return table;
}

void ht_destroy(ht* table) {
    // First free allocated keys.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < table->capacity; i++) {
        if (table->entries[i].key != NULL) {
            free((void*)table->entries[i].key);
        }
    }

    // Then free entries array and table itself.
    free(table->entries);
    free(table);
}

#define FNV_OFFSET 14695981039346656037UL
#define FNV_PRIME 1099511628211UL

// Return 64-bit FNV-1a hash for key (NUL-terminated). See description:
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler–Noll–Vo_hash_function
static uint64_t hash_key(const char* key) {
    uint64_t hash = FNV_OFFSET;
    for (const char* p = key; *p; p++) {
        hash ^= (uint64_t)(unsigned char)(*p);
        hash *= FNV_PRIME;
    }
    return hash;
}

void* ht_get(ht* table, const char* key) {
    // AND hash with capacity-1 to ensure it's within entries array.
    uint64_t hash = hash_key(key);
    size_t index = (size_t)(hash & (uint64_t)(table->capacity - 1));

    // Loop till we find an empty entry.
    while (table->entries[index].key != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(key, table->entries[index].key) == 0) {
            // Found key, return value.
            return table->entries[index].value;
        }
        // Key wasn't in this slot, move to next (linear probing).
        index++;
        if (index >= table->capacity) {
            // At end of entries array, wrap around.
            index = 0;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

// Internal function to set an entry (without expanding table).
static const char* ht_set_entry(ht_entry* entries, size_t capacity,
        const char* key, void* value, size_t* plength) {
    // AND hash with capacity-1 to ensure it's within entries array.
    uint64_t hash = hash_key(key);
    size_t index = (size_t)(hash & (uint64_t)(capacity - 1));

    // Loop till we find an empty entry.
    while (entries[index].key != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(key, entries[index].key) == 0) {
            // Found key (it already exists), update value.
            entries[index].value = value;
            return entries[index].key;
        }
        // Key wasn't in this slot, move to next (linear probing).
        index++;
        if (index >= capacity) {
            // At end of entries array, wrap around.
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    // Didn't find key, allocate+copy if needed, then insert it.
    if (plength != NULL) {
        key = strdup(key);
        if (key == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }
        (*plength)++;
    }
    entries[index].key = (char*)key;
    entries[index].value = value;
    return key;
}

// Expand hash table to twice its current size. Return true on success,
// false if out of memory.
static bool ht_expand(ht* table) {
    // Allocate new entries array.
    size_t new_capacity = table->capacity * 2;
    if (new_capacity < table->capacity) {
        return false;  // overflow (capacity would be too big)
    }
    ht_entry* new_entries = calloc(new_capacity, sizeof(ht_entry));
    if (new_entries == NULL) {
        return false;
    }

    // Iterate entries, move all non-empty ones to new table's entries.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < table->capacity; i++) {
        ht_entry entry = table->entries[i];
        if (entry.key != NULL) {
            ht_set_entry(new_entries, new_capacity, entry.key,
                         entry.value, NULL);
        }
    }

    // Free old entries array and update this table's details.
    free(table->entries);
    table->entries = new_entries;
    table->capacity = new_capacity;
    return true;
}

const char* ht_set(ht* table, const char* key, void* value) {
    assert(value != NULL);
    if (value == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    // If length will exceed half of current capacity, expand it.
    if (table->length >= table->capacity / 2) {
        if (!ht_expand(table)) {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    // Set entry and update length.
    return ht_set_entry(table->entries, table->capacity, key, value,
                        &table->length);
}

size_t ht_length(ht* table) {
    return table->length;
}

hti ht_iterator(ht* table) {
    hti it;
    it._table = table;
    it._index = 0;
    return it;
}

bool ht_next(hti* it) {
    // Loop till we've hit end of entries array.
    ht* table = it->_table;
    while (it->_index < table->capacity) {
        size_t i = it->_index;
        it->_index++;
        if (table->entries[i].key != NULL) {
            // Found next non-empty item, update iterator key and value.
            ht_entry entry = table->entries[i];
            it->key = entry.key;
            it->value = entry.value;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

ht.h:

```
// Simple hash table implemented in C.

#ifndef _HT_H
#define _HT_H

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// Hash table structure: create with ht_create, free with ht_destroy.
typedef struct ht ht;

// Create hash table and return pointer to it, or NULL if out of memory.
ht* ht_create(void);

// Free memory allocated for hash table, including allocated keys.
void ht_destroy(ht* table);

// Get item with given key (NUL-terminated) from hash table. Return
// value (which was set with ht_set), or NULL if key not found.
void* ht_get(ht* table, const char* key);

// Set item with given key (NUL-terminated) to value (which must not
// be NULL). If not already present in table, key is copied to newly
// allocated memory (keys are freed automatically when ht_destroy is
// called). Return address of copied key, or NULL if out of memory.
const char* ht_set(ht* table, const char* key, void* value);

// Return number of items in hash table.
size_t ht_length(ht* table);

// Hash table iterator: create with ht_iterator, iterate with ht_next.
typedef struct {
    const char* key;  // current key
    void* value;      // current value

    // Don't use these fields directly.
    ht* _table;       // reference to hash table being iterated
    size_t _index;    // current index into ht._entries
} hti;

// Return new hash table iterator (for use with ht_next).
hti ht_iterator(ht* table);

// Move iterator to next item in hash table, update iterator's key
// and value to current item, and return true. If there are no more
// items, return false. Don't call ht_set during iteration.
bool ht_next(hti* it);

#endif // _HT_H
```

GNU C: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hash-Search-Function.html
UTHash: https://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/
Ben Hoyt: https://benhoyt.com/writings/hash-table-in-c/

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please share the code instead of images of code.

Comment: Aside: Rather than attempt to out think the compiler, trust your compiler to emit good code: `(size_t)(hash & (uint64_t)(capacity - 1))` --> `hash % capacity`.  This later form also handles `capacity` when it is not a power-of-2 - something code should be doing to cope with weak hashes.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screenshot, I see:

```
void *data = &i;
```

This is storing the address of a variable that exists on the stack inside your `test_hashtable` function.  When you store that pointer in your hash table and then the function exits, you cannot rely on the data it points at.  The data is gone, and the memory may be used for something else.

So what you've encountered is undefined behavior.  If you wish to store an int value then you'll need to either allocate memory for it or actually jam it into the pointer (which is a fairly common practice for any data types that fit inside a pointer).

Here is an example of storing the integer inside the actual pointer:

```
// store
const char *key = "Gate";
int i = 10;
void *data;
memcpy(&data, &i, sizeof(i));
ht_set(hashtable, key, data);

// retrieve
void *result = ht_get(hashtable, key);
int value;
memcpy(&value, &result, sizeof(value));
```

However, you'll notice one problem here, which is that you cannot store the integer `0` in your table due to the calling semantics of `ht_get` which uses a NULL value to indicate no data.  So, unless you want to change your interface to return a "found" indicator along with the data, then your only option is to actually allocate:

```
// store
const char *key = "Gate";
int i = 10;
int *data = malloc(sizeof(i));
if (data) {
    *data = i;
    ht_set(hashtable, key, data);
}

// retrieve
void *result = ht_get(hashtable, key);
if (result) {
    int value = *(int*)result;
}

// note: you'll need to `free` the data when you remove the key from your hash table.
```